# How to compile your flex application for Iphone Using Adobe Flash CS5?

Tags: iphone, apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, mxml

How to compile your flex (Flash Builder) application for Iph*ne Using Adobe Flash CS5?

A User can Install an app having it as compiled binary?

Comment: are you just trying to pick a fight? Until Jobs decides for some miraculous reason to allow Flash on the iPhone, you're out of luck.

Comment: Agree with CookieOfFortune. Good luck getting that accepted!

Comment: @CookieOfFortune: I don't think OP meant running Flash directly on iPhone but rather using Adobe's exporting tool they had added with CS5. But just as Jeffry Houser explained in his answer, that's a whole can of worms right on its own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: You can't.

Longer answer:

Adobe created a "Flash to iPhone" technology that allowed developers to create Flash applications and export them to the iPhone.  There were other technologies--such as Unity, Titanium, and MonoTouch--that used similar approaches and it seemed as if that was an acceptable approach to building iPhone apps.  Adobe included that technology in Flash Professional CS5.

Due to licensing changes with the iPhone SDK developer's agreement (Clause 3.3.1 ) , using such technology is now a violation of this agreement.  Subsequently Adobe has announced that they will cease all development of their "Flash to iPhone" technology.

http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2010/04/20/on-adobe-flash-cs5-and-iphone-applications/

I assume that means such technology will not be added to Flash Builder.

For reasons I'm unclear on, Flash Professional and The Flex Framework do not work well together.  You cannot use Flash Professional to build Flex applications.  Therefore there is no known way to build Flex applications for the iPhone.

You're more than welcome to build your application in Flash Professional without the Flex Framework.  It is unknown how this clause is going to be enforced, if at all.  But, from a business perspective I wouldn't recommend it.

**Update 12/23/2010**
Since this got an upvote recently, I wanted to clarify that since my original answer, Apple has changed their licensing agreement once again allowing third party tools, such as Adobe's iPhone Exporter to be used.  Adobe has resumed development on the project, and it is expected to appear in Flash Builder at some future point. Many including me, are hoping it will make it's way into the Burrito release, believed to be Flex and Flash Builder 4.5.  Workflow and component set is expected to be similar to the Burrito mobile projects; although they only support AIR for Android in the tooling right now.

Some say it is possible to use a [command line compiler](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/packagerforiphone/) to deploy flex to the iPhone..

Comment: You sound angry; I'm unsure what points you're responding too.

As far as I knew, the only way to install an app onto an Apple device was through the App store; which is controlled by Apple.  So, at this time users will not be able to download and install apps from your site onto an Apple Mobile device.  If you had a developer account you can install it to your own devices; and I believe there is a way to distribute it to a limited number of beta testers; but haven't researched the ecosystem.

Comment: My comment above was in a response to a comment that is now gone.